# Segmentation fault when trying to print out/load a 2d array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, io, segmentation-fault, text-files

When I try to run my code, it compiles with no problem. When I try to run it, however, I get `line x: segmentation fault`, x being the line the error is supposedly on, but it changes by +1 every time I try to run the program again, which seems strange. Below is the relevant code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "image.h" // Has the prototypes for the functions

using namespace std;   

int** load(string imageFile, int &length, int &height) {
    ifstream file(imageFile);
    if(file.is_open()) {
        file >> length; 
        int** array = new int*[length];
        file >> height;
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            array[i] = new int[height]; 
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                file >> array[i][j];
                if(array[i][j] > 255 || array[i][j] < 0) {
                    cout << "Image is corrupted." << endl;
                    file.close();
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        file.close();
        return array;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

void show(int **image, int length, int height) {
    cout << "The height of the matrix is: " << height << endl;
    cout << "The length of the matrix is: " << length << endl;
    cout << "The matrix is: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            cout << " " << image[i][j]; 
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int height = 0;
    int length = 0;
    int **image = load("../resource/imagecorrupted.txt", length, height);
    image = load("../resource/image.txt", length, height);
    show(image, length, height);
}
```

This is the output:

`Image is corrupted.
Image is corrupted. //Not sure why this shows twice to be honest
The height of the matrix is: 8 // but that seems like the least of my worries
The length of the matrix is: 10
The matrix is: 
-bash: line xx: xxxxx Segmentation fault`

Not sure what could be causing this, any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

I totally forgot to show what the inputs were meant to be. I apologize. Here they are: 

`10  8
0   255 255 255 0   0   255 255 255 0
255 0   255 255 0   0   255 255 0   255
255 255 0   255 255 255 255 0   255 255
255 255 255 0   255 255 0   255 255 255
255 255 255 355 0   0   255 255 255 255
255 255 255 255 0   0   255 255 255 255
255 255 255 0   255 255 0   255 255 255
0   0   0   255 255 255 255 0   0   0`

That is what is contained in `image.txt`. `imagecorrupted.txt` is identical, with one value switched from 255 to 355 (it's intentionally meant to fail). The `10` and `8` are the length/height of the matrix.

EDIT 2:

Tried to add a `delete` function between each `load` call, to no avail, though I'm sure there's something here I'm not getting. This is the code used:

```
void free(int **image, int &length, int &height) {
    if(image) {
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if(image[i]) {
                delete[] image[i];
            }
        }
        delete[] image;
    }
}
```

And what I did in main was:

```
 int **image = load("../resource/imagecorrupted.txt", length, height);
 free(image, length, height);
 image = load("../resource/image.txt", length, height);
```

Comment: Not the cause of your segmentation fault, but you leak all the memory you allocate. Better use `vector<vector<int>>` rather than `int**`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a memory leak. To avoid the leak and to have better bounds checking you should consider using `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` rather than `int**`.

Your crash is due to the second failure. When the second `load` fails, it returns 0, i.e. `nullptr` (it is recommended to use `nullptr` rather than 0 in this case). Later, `show` tries to dereference this `nullptr` -- causing segmentation fault.

If you insist on using raw pointers, rather than vectors or, the second best, unique_ptr then you must make sure the allocations are cleaned up on failure of `load`, and between consecutive successful calls to `load` (and at the end).

## Edit

The second call is corrupted because of the integer 355. Also, your column's and rows seem to be transposed (rows are treated as columns and columns treated as rows).

Comment: Thanks for the response @MichaelVeksler ! This is for an assignment, and we have yet to learn vectors, though I'm sure they would be much better for this if I could use them... When you say I must make sure the allocations are cleaned up of failure, do you mean to `delete []` them, or something else? Also, do you know why the second `load` fails? I just don't understand why it would.

Comment: @Spago you should `delete[] array[i]` for all inner arrays that you did allocate (not all are allocated in case of a failure), and finally you should call `delete[] array`

Comment: @Spago The second `load` fails due to something in the input. It is impossible to tell without seeing the input. I suggest you print i,j together with `Image is corrupted`. This should give you a hint where the input is corrupted.

Comment: So should I be calling a `delete` function (I do have one, it just isn't shown here; I wasn't sure whether it was important or not...) between each `load` in main? Also, I apologize for the missing inputs, I've edited my post above accordingly!

Comment: So I tried added the delete (`free`) function between each `load` call, but that seems to have had no effect on the issue (I've also edited the post and added the `free` code I'm using)

Comment: @Spago deleting vs. leaking is another issue, so it won't improve this specific segmentation fault

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188661/discussion-between-spago-and-michael-veksler).